# Difference between cat file.txt | sort -u and cat file.txt | uniq

Tags: linux, sort, uniq

I want to know the difference between sort -u and uniq.
I tried below command to get the count for the unique strings in a file , sort -u and uniq provides the same output from my knowledge. Then why did it provide two different count.

```bsh
cat test.txt | sort -u | wc -l 
351
cat test.txt | uniq | wc -l
370
```

Why does it shows two different line count ?

Comment: Uniq needs sorted input. Is your input sorted?

Comment: no my input is not sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `uniq` doesn't need sorted input - but it is true that `uniq` will only remove consecutive duplicate lines.

The difference is that:

- `sort` sorts a file and (using its `-u` option) can also eliminate duplicate lines, which will now all be consecutive as they have been sorted.
- `uniq` deletes consecutive duplicate lines.  It also has options to output only duplicated lines (**one** of each with `-d`, or **all** dupes with `-D`), and can output a count of how many times a line appeared in the input (`-c`).  It also has other options to control how dupes are detected, such as skipping fields and comparing only N characters in a line.
- the output of `sort` can, of course, be piped into `uniq` if you want to combine the features of both.

`sort -u` is useful when you either don't care about preserving the order of the input file, or actually want it sorted - but want no duplicates at all in the output.

`uniq` is useful when preserving the input order is required, or when you only care about consecutive dupes - e.g. when you want to uniq an already-sorted file (no need to waste CPU and IOPS sorting it again); or remove all but one of consecutive line feeds between paragraphs (for example, `pdftotext` often produces lots of blank space between lines or paragraphs - `uniq` can remove the extras making it easier to read or edit).

Answer (score 4):

`uniq` needs the input to be already sorted. Duplicates that don't appear sequentially won't be eliminated:

```
~ printf %s\\n 1 2 1 | uniq
1
2
1
~ printf %s\\n 1 2 1 | sort | uniq
1
2
~ printf %s\\n 1 2 1 | sort -u
1
2
```